# Alter Time Based On Calculation

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to add/subtract X hours from my datetime variables based off the result of a calculation.  I tried the below syntax

```
string lsdt;
var hours = (dt1 - dt2).TotalHours;
var CalculatedDT = Convert.ToDateTime(lsdt.AddHours(hours));
```

Which presents me with the error

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'AddHours' and no extension method 'AddHours' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

What is the proper way to subtract the variable `hours` from the `string` variable `lsdt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lsdt` is *not* a `DateTime` variable, but a `string`. Therefore you get that error message:

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'AddHours' and no extension
>   method 'AddHours' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be
>   found

You have to first convert your `string` to `DateTime` struct:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(lsdt);
```

Then you can use `AddHours` method available for the `DateTime` struct:

```
var hours = (dt1 - dt2).TotalHours;
var CalculatedDT = dt.AddHours(hours);
```

For more safely approach, as suggested by Joel Etheron, you could also use `TryParse` to check the validity of your `string` on the parsing before you use it:

```
DateTime dt;
bool result = DateTime.TryParse(lsdt, out dt);
if (!result) {
    //Do something, don't continue
}
```

Comment: `dt.AddHours()` will give you a dateTime object, then why are you converting again to DateTime?

Comment: What worked for me was var CalculatedDT = Convert.ToDateTime(lsdt).AddHours(hours);

Comment: For exception safety I would recommend TryParse over Parse.

Comment: @MichaelMormon: yes, the idea is to make the `string` into `DateTime` so that you could use the `AddHours` method rather than use it in the `string` itself

Comment: @Ian - yes I realized that after I tested your code and realized I could use Convert.ToDateTime() on the variable THEN add in the .AddHours() element